# Vertical margin between list items

Tags: html, css

So I have an list that contains items. The list shall look a bit like a table. Each list item represents a row. Each paragraph represents a column. The *table* just have 2 columns. So paragraph one shall float to the left and paragraph two shall float to the right.

So that's what I did:
No real html/css, just some pseudo code. But I guess you get it.

```
ul list-style-type none
  li
    p float left
    p float right
    div clear both
  li
    ...
  li
    ...
  ..
/ul
```

Yet there are some very huge margins around each item: But I want to have a very small margin between each item. I already replaced the paragraphs with div elements which made it a bit better. But that's still too much margin.

Then I've forced (`!important`) the marign to 0 which did not help at all. Negating the margin works. Hooray.. But this is kinda silly, no?

So my actual question: **Are there other / better ways to reduce the margin between list items [but setting a negative margin]?**

Comment: Try make a pen with everything, we need to see: http://codepen.io/

Comment: I would suggest you look what actually causes the margins. Then it is much easier to remove them than if you are just _guessing_. So open the development console of your browser and start checking the DOM elements. You will see the geometry of each item. This allows to identify what is actually causing the margins.

Comment: @arkascha uhm. A paragraph just does add a huge margin, no? There is nothing adding an extra margin (inspected with dev tools)

Comment: My guess is the elements are gaining margins from parent element(s) in your page. You can override the margins by setting the new value, and using `!important` after the value. Example: `margin: 0 !important;` Paragraph tags by default do add margins, yes, by 1em on the top and bottom.

Comment: @DrewKennedy that's what I did (meant by > forced)

Comment: We can only guess without seeing the actual code, but if there are no margins as you claim then I think the "margin" you might be referring to is actually the fact that when you clear floats, the next row of floats won't start untill below both cleared floats above, like here: http://jsfiddle.net/k6s89acL/ (notice "margin" between "Oi 1" and "Oi 3").

Comment: Also, there's no need to add an extra element to clear floats. There are a number of ways to "self clear" floats through the parent. The easiest being `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: @powerbuoy or `clear: both`  on each `li` tag.

Comment: @Brettetete avoid using `!important`. Try to use a more specific selector to override attribute values.

Comment: As everyone else has already pointed out, we'll need to see the actual code to help properly, but (given your markup) I am going to guess that the extra space at the bottom of each list element comes from the margin at the bottom of your paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment:

Paragraphs naturally have a margin ...

```css
ul{
  list-style: none;
  }
li{
  /* To demonstarte issue */
  background: #dadada;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  }
p{
  background: red;
  }
/* Self clear content */
li:after{
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
  }
.left{
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
  }
.right{
  float: right;
  width: 40%;
  }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <p class="left">Left floated paragraph</p>
    <p class="right">Right floated paragraph</p>
    </li>
  <li>
    <p class="left">Left floated paragraph</p>
    <p class="right">Right floated paragraph</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Once your reset the margin ...

```css
ul{
  list-style: none;
}
li{
  /* To demonstarte issue */
  background: #dadada;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0;
}
p{
  background: red;
  /* Remove the "natural" margin */
  margin: 0;
}
/* Self clear content */
li:after{
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.left{
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
}
.right{
  float: right;
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <p class="left">Left floated paragraph</p>
    <p class="right">Right floated paragraph</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p class="left">Left floated paragraph</p>
    <p class="right">Right floated paragraph</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

... assuming this is what you're after?